# How can I remove a section from Fluida WordPress theme that is disabled?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, themes

I have a WordPress theme installed called Fluida. There is a place to enable or disable portions of the home page, however, I have disabled the last section and now it just repeats what the first section says. http://cannabisendorser.com. I like the theme and would like to see it corrected. I have tried searching in many places including here, but the only thing I could find was premium support which is $25 and I'm not sure they could even answer this. I have also tried to use display: none; on this section, but it is an inner article that affects others as well. I would like to stay away from the PHP if possible.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come up with my own solution, ff this ever comes up again. #post-86, .post-86 page type-page status-publish hentry {display:none;} using your post number of course will eliminate the section and not affect other pages.